# Typecasting in enumeration not working in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, enumeration

```
enum CardPosition: CGFloat {
    case top = UIScreen.main.bounds.height //This line has the error "Raw value for enum case must be a literal"
    case middle = 500
    case bottom = 590
}
```

In the top case, I guess it doesn't return a CGFloat, but it also can't be typecast as a CGFloat for some reason using the "as" keyword and I don't know why. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an enum that has a raw value that is a CGFloat.

What's wrong with the `top` case is that only a *literal number* is legal as a raw value. You cannot assign a variable like `UIScreen.main.bounds.height`. You must write out an actual number, there and then.

Taking a longer view, it looks like what you want here might not be an enum, or might not be an enum that takes a raw value. For example, you can have an enum that has an *associated* value:

```
enum CardPosition {
    case top(CGFloat)
    case middle(CGFloat)
    case bottom(CGFloat)
}
```

Now you can attach the value at initialization time:

```
let myPosition = CardPosition.top(UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
let myOtherPosition = CardPosition.middle(500)
```

Note that you cannot mix and match; if we're going to use an associated value, then this enum can't have a fixed raw value.

Comment: What if all of the positions are mathematically related to UIScreen.main.bounds.height? What is the type that that will return? I could change the enumeration type to something not CGFloat but idk what it should be

Comment: Did you read my answer? This has nothing to do with CGFloat.